# A bug in console.log function in Nodejs ?

Tags: html, node.js, newline, linefeed

I've accidentally came across this weird buggy phenomenon when writing code with Nodejs.

I get input from a form, which are comprised of a series of ID's, 
delimited with **New Line(hit Enter)**

To handle them, I use the **split** function to split them into an array:

```
var array = orig_input.split('\n');
```

For the debugging purpose,I print them.

```
console.log('orig_input = ' + input);
console.log('array = ' + array);
```

Well, here comes the first weird output:

```
orig_input = 1111
2222
,2222
```

Look! the supposed output string **'array = 1111'** is swallowed !

My first thought is **array[0]** has some **delete** characters.

So I change the code to do some tests, like:

```
console.log('orig_input = ' + input);
console.log('***********************************' + array[0] + array[1]);
```

Wow, yet another weird output:

```
orig_input = 1111
2222
2222*******************************1111
```

It seems there is some weird wrap or something.

And finally, after some boring testing and debugging, it turns out that

```
I used the wrong split character, it should be '\r\n', instead of '\n'
```

We know that the former is the MS-style of new line, and the latter is the *nix-style of new line.

**So question is**

```
Is this a bug of console.log function in **Nodejs** ?

Anyone would explain this?
```

Comment: HTML has no real concept of newlines. HTTP, however, does use CR+LF.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph. Thanks for clarification. I've changed the title.

Comment: Node.js's behaviour looks right to me. Each `\r` causes the characters following to start printing at the beginning of the current line, (it's a `carriage return` character) overwriting the characters that were previously printed there. Is that what you don't understand, or was there something else?

Comment: It looks like you copy/pasted your output incorrectly, because your two outputs show completely different behaviors, plus your second example doesn't have the `,` that should be between array elements (but your first one does).

Comment: @ Aaron Dufour  when you print an array, it will add `,` for you.

Comment: @larmbr I understand that.  The fact that there is no `,` in `2222*******************************1111` is what bothers me.  How come there is one in `,2222` if the only difference was the constant string?